# how to make keyframe animations in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

How to make keyframe animations in Chrome

## fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tPw8J/

## html

```
<button class="loading">btn</button>
```

## css

```
@keyframes animation_loading {
    from { background-position:0 0; }
    to { background-position:25px 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animation_loading {
    from { background-position:0 0; }
    to { background-position:25px 0; }
}

button.loading {
    background-image:url(//www.dynaccount.com/button.bg-loading.png);
    animation:animation_loading 0.5s linear infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "How to make keyframe animations in Chrome"

You'll need to include the [`-webkit`](http://caniuse.com/css-animation) prefix on the `animation` property:

```
button.loading {
    background-image:url(//www.dynaccount.com/button.bg-loading.png);
    -moz-animation: animation_loading 0.5s linear infinite; /* FF 15 & below */
    -webkit-animation: animation_loading 0.5s linear infinite;
     animation: animation_loading 0.5s linear infinite;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tPw8J/3/